# How to fix "insecure content was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource"

Tags: html, google-chrome, https, google-chrome-console

This URL: https://slowapi.com

I can't find the insecure content and the Chrome keeps complaining,

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Use that new Security tab in developer tools. Should show you exactly which resource is insecure.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"Mixed Content" warnings occur when an HTTPS page is asked to load a resource over HTTP.

This is dangerous because the insecure resources are vulnerable to alteration by an active attacker or eavesdropping by a passive attacker, which violates the user's expectation of security for an HTTPS page.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content?hl=en

Comment: What about the development phase? Do I really need to set up HTTPS just to be able to test downloads? Where is the logic in that?

Answer (score 67):

Update the links via adding a meta tag like below

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

**Note:** This is a **hot fix** when you update your production from non-ssl to ssl, anyway you have to fix all the links one by one to https.

Comment: It does not help

Comment: It did help me.

Comment: Deprecated. It's no longer working.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to access via "http" on a "https" site, its best to use "https" content. You shouldn't access insecure data on a secure channel.

Comment: Sometimes just use 'http' instead of 'https' can solve this issue.

Comment: i call my laravel apis from ionic app that hosted app on index page as application and my server https and i call https but error said please call https i dont know my dokcer use ngnix and how can i configure docker or ngnix https://stackoverflow.com/q/56157129/308578

Comment: Really? What about the development phase? Where is the logic in that?

Answer (score 2):

I had this error with an iframe to another website.
I changed the src from "https://website.com/folder" to "https://website.com/folder/index.php" and for some reason it works.

Comment: I had the same problem! I added /index.html and it worked! You saved the day

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nginx as a reverse proxy, modify the ssl server block to include this line.

```
server {
    listen 443 SSL;
    # Proxy settings
    add_header 'Content-Security-Policy' 'upgrade-insecure-requests';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the blocker was at the path. The path I used it was not allowed by the HTTP server. So, make sure your HTTP server allows the path toward your downloads.

My case. I use Flask with path outside "static" directory. Flask does not allow that by default. Once I put in "static" directory (or I instructed Flask to allow my new path), it worked and the error disappeared without any other action from my side.

I hope it helps those who still have this issue.