# OpenCart 1.5.6.4: Category images not loading over https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, opencart

I am trying to enable `ssl` in all pages of [nicehair.gr](https://www.nicehair.gr), but in every category page there are some images (category images) loading over http.

([whynopadlock](https://www.whynopadlock.com/results/7a275354-c00e-40c9-b508-12bb75d09295))

For example:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.nicehair.gr/mallia' was loaded
>   over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://nicehair.gr/image/data/BANNERS/hair_oil_category.jpg'. This
>   content should also be served over HTTPS.

I have enable the `ssl` in the admin panel.

Here is the `/config.php`:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.nicehair.gr/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.nicehair.gr/');
```

`/admin/config.php`:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://www.nicehair.gr/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'https://www.nicehair.gr/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.nicehair.gr/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'https://www.nicehair.gr/');
```

And the `.htaccess` file:

```
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php .php5 .php4 .php3

RewriteEngine on
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oraiamallia\.gr$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.oraiamallia\.gr$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/nicehair\.gr" [R=301,L]

# URL CANONICALIZATION 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.               [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[a-z]{2,6})$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$       http://www.%1/$1      [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} nicehair\.gr [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.nicehair.gr/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: As I checked category page, Category image is showing properly https://www.nicehair.gr/mallia/ca-vourtses--chtenes-79

Comment: @VipulJethva The categories one level up not showing properly : https://www.nicehair.gr/mallia

Comment: See the attached image https://i.imgur.com/aITuFtu.png . I am showing all of the images.

Comment: @VipulJethva the problem is that the images not loading over https, they load over http which breaks ssl padlock

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the insecure content "was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure prefetch resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178135/where-is-the-insecure-content-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure)