# Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/sw.js' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com/about/'

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

In my site to which I added PWA feature.

I am trying to cache `/about` folder. But I have error message in console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/sw.js' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://example.com/about/'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS..

How to overcome this?

Now I get an error like:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Request failed

On console. I think I miss a `{{ site.baseurl }}`somewhere because in custom domain this code works.

---

**Edit**

Problem solved, There is a url problem in file.

I need to add `{{ site.baseurl }}/index.html` instead of `{{ site.baseurl }}index.html`

Comment: Can you add any details like code used? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I have updated my question. Please review it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the insecure content "was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure prefetch resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178135/where-is-the-insecure-content-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure)