# Fastapi with jinja rendered image does not display image inside container run

Tags: html, http, jinja2, fastapi, amazon-app-runner

```
from routers import routers_main
app = FastAPI()

#Mount the static files directory
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
app.include_router(routers_main.router)
```

My router file has the following

```
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/", response_class=HTMLResponse)
def home_page(request: Request):
    image_url_1 = request.url_for("static", path=f"website_flow.png")
    return templates.TemplateResponse("home.html", {"request": request, "visits": visits, "image_1": image_url_1})
```

Inside the html I have added this

```
  <img src="{{ image_1 }}" alt="Image 12" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
```

It displays correctly with uvicorn locally but the issue occurs when I run the fastapi as a container with the command

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:3400", "-w", "4", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "main:app"]
```

The directory structure is

```
--- main.py
--- router/
------ routers_main.py
--- static/
------ website_flow.png
```

The container is working correctly in macos but fails in the container of aws apprunner

My dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11.2-slim-buster

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
# Install PyTorch and torchvision with cpu
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2 --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

# add app
COPY . .

# Specify the command to be executed when running the container
# CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
# CMD ["gunicorn -b 127.0.0.1:3100 -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app"]
CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:3400", "-w", "4", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "main:app"]
# RUN THE BELOW COMMAND AFTER BUILDING
# docker run -d -p 3400:3400 --name my-container my-dock
```

The container displays html correctly in local but does not do so in aws apprunner container.
I get the following in the browser console which is missing in my local browser console

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://nhs6qhaxjj.us-east-1.awsapprunner.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure element 'http://nhs6qhaxjj.us-east-1.awsapprunner.com/static/telugu_dictionary_flowchart.png'. This request was automatically upgraded to HTTPS, For more information see https://blog.chromium.org/2019/10/no-more-mixed-messages-about-https.html
website_flow.png:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

dockerfile is in same directory as main.py

I have tried the following:

Adding this tag to the header tag of html

```
< meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

Adding middleware

```
 from fastapi.middleware.httpsredirect import HTTPSRedirectMiddleware
app.add_middleware(HTTPSRedirectMiddleware)
```

I strongly suspect there's an issue with AWS containers or the issue is arising due to macos (my local OS) and ubuntu difference

Edit: Trying out from the suggestions in the github issue:

1. @app.middleware("http")
2. app.add_middleware(HTTPSRedirectMiddleware)
3. --proxy-headers with uvicorn and guvicorn

None of these work. My fastapi version is fastapi==0.100.0 with starlette==0.27.0

Comment: Could it be that you're not copying the `static` directory in the `Dockerfile`?

Comment: editted, it's working properly in the local container but when i launch the container in aws apprunner it fails.

Comment: can you add the `Dockerfile` or, if public, share a link? So we can better understand why it does not work, which might have to do with some settings of `aws` or build

Comment: added dockerfile and additional comments

Comment: There are a couple of suggestions in [this github issue](https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/538), maybe try them?

Comment: For some strange reason none of them works!

Answer (score 1):

After the update on the question, the error is self explanatory:

The issue is caused by the fact that your client's browser is requesting an insecure URL after using a secure one to connect to your app. Probably this is a misconfiguration of your server, but you should be capable of setting somewhere (I don't know the `aws` ecosystem) to force redirect. `FastAPI` should automatically adapt to use `https`.

Below a link with the complete answer to the same problem

[How to fix "insecure content was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35178135/how-to-fix-insecure-content-was-loaded-over-https-but-requested-an-insecure-re)

Comment: The solutions mentioned there actually donot work for me. I don't understand why the issue of http or https is coming as neither is mentioned in the container or code so the default should be taken.

Comment: #Hrushi it may not be due to the fact that your app explicitly mentions `http` or `https` but the request the client makes or the infrastructure between the two. Maybe there is a setting that excludes certain paths from being `https` protected. This is difficoult to say because it depends on your configuration on `aws`

Comment: How @M.O. mentioned in the comments, it could be also due to the app not knowing if it's an `http` or `https` server and generating an absolute path with `http` instead of `https`.  You could try with https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#httpsredirectmiddleware